# Fetch source code from linux to windows

Tags: clearcase

I have two solaris servers.
One server is for clearcase licenses and another is for source code repository.

Unfortunately, somehow licensing server is not working with telnet (its running in single user mode).
As a result, I cannot open ClearCase Explorer as the licensing server is not working.

Now, I wanted to get the sourcecode from the repository server to my local (windows) system.
How can we get that?

Comment: Do you have any colleague with a recent snapshot view of the same vob you want the source code?

Comment: Unfortunately no... And we were used to create dynamic views

Comment: Any possibility to reboot/restart that license server?

Comment: Is there any way to bring the license server to muti user mode.? The server is pingingm but not able to telnet.

Comment: Yes. I did reboot the server, If possible, can you please let me know the command for soft reboot

Comment: If you did reboot the server, you don't need that command, do you? If not, I wiould try one of the answers from https://serverfault.com/q/352712/783

Comment: Its a solaris server. Not windows server.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/solaris/shut-down-or-reboot-a-solaris-system/ then?

Comment: I will check and get back

Comment: Meanwhile, do you have any idea on fetching the source code from other linux server to a windows machine? Please let me know. Is there any chance to get it? Because, if i cant connect to the license server, how can i get the code..

Comment: All the way, we are looking to migrate the code from linux server to GIT repository.

Comment: Note sure: maybe cyou can setup another license server? (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21308308)

Comment: I have rebooted my license server. But still i couldn't access it over Telnet.

Comment: That means the license service might not have restarted: can you check the logs on that server? If not, it is best to contact IBM support.